# When button is clicked move it in front of everything

Tags: android, button, android-animation

I want to move button if front of everything in the XML, when it is clicked.
Button animates when it is clicked and background changes and is overflows button and i want to move it in front of everything.

```
slide_up2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_up2);
btnUp.bringToFront();
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(),R.animator.obj2);
set.setTarget(flBlur);
flBlur.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
set.start();
slide_up2.setAnimationListener(this);
```

Comment: If you demonstrate how you have attempted to solve/ approach the challenge then people will be able to help you easier.

Comment: btnUp.bringToFront(); was the attempt